# UITextView view appears, but there is no text in it

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

UPDATE: I have put the entire project [here](https://github.com/bryanhanson/MyConfig) for inspection.  There are small changes relative to the initial code below, but the behavior is the same.  Some how `pushTextView` is not making it into the view hierarchy, but I don't see it.  Thanks.

--- Original Question Below ---

I have the function below in a view controller.  When I click a button in the app, this code is called.  What happens is the view appears (entire device takes on a white bkgnd from previous appearance, status bar is visible), but no text is displayed (I'm aiming for the default text formatting for now). No errors or crashes, so I'm sure I've either forgotten the obvious or I'm doing something silly.  I'm on Xcode 6.0.1.

```
func pushTextView(theString: String) {
    let msgString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: theString)
    let r = view.bounds

    let txtStore = NSTextStorage()
    let layMan = NSLayoutManager()
    let txtCon = NSTextContainer(size: r.size)
    let txtView = UITextView(frame:r, textContainer:txtCon)

    layMan.addTextContainer(txtCon)
    txtStore.addLayoutManager(layMan)

    txtView.attributedText = msgString
    txtView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    txtView.scrollEnabled = true
    txtView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let inset = 0.2 * width // width = device width in points, defined elsewhere
    txtView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(inset, inset, inset, inset)
    txtView.selectable = false
    txtView.editable = false

    view.addSubview(txtView)               
}
```

Comment: So the textView is visible but only no text is visible? I guess you have already checked that you msgString is not empty? Could you test it with Plain Text too, just to be sure that there is not another mistake here?

Comment: Yes, the string is not empty (but it's always good to check!).  I can echo it with `println`.  What would I change to make it plain text? `let msgString = "my message"` but then `txtView` won't take a plain string w/o some other changes, which I'm not sure of...

Comment: Try out: txtView.text = "This is a Plain Text String"

Comment: Hmm. But you are able to write text in your textView? (activate editable first)

Comment: Alright, this is weird, one time I clicked on the textView, the keyboard came up but as I typed, the txt was not appearing anywhere.  Tried to repeat, and now the keyboard won't come up.  So I think I'm not really seeing the textView as I thought, or there is some sweet spot in it that is reactive (which I can find anymore).  I'm in the simulator by the way.

Comment: There is sometimes a problem with the keyboard appearance in the simulator. Open it by using: Hardware - Keyboard - Toggle Software Keyboard. I would suggest that you uncomment all "useless" staff of your code and just implement a simple textview, and then try to add every part of your code step by step, and check out what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61795/discussion-between-bryan-hanson-and-derdida).

Comment: a) embed it in a scrollview ...oh and also b) use a red bicolour to see if you really see the view

Comment: Scroll view on (no change) and I can change the view background color successfully, so I believe I am really looking at the view.

Comment: Check over on the chat link just above if you don't mind.